# Quelle différence y a-t-il entre « se coltiner X », « se taper X », etc. ?

Tags: usage, registre-familier

> {par ex.} : Franchement, **se taper** 1h30 de bouchons pour se faire recaler sans aucun motif valable, c'est plus qu'insupportable, à boycotter en masse !

Quand on parle d’une chose désagréable imposée à soi, d’une tâche/corvée du genre qu’on se voit mal faire de gaieté de cœur, on dit :

> **se coltiner** une chose / **se taper** X / **se coller** X / **se payer** X / **se farcir** X / **se palucher** X

Il me semble d'ailleurs que « **refiler** » en revanche, quoique synonyme, ne s'emploie que de façon non pronominale.

Est-ce qu’on y perçoit une différence de sens, d'usage, de registre, de fréquence d'utilisation ou de quoi que ce soit d'autre ?

Comment: Je connais (en France) "se coltiner", "se taper", "se payer", "se farcir", mais pas "se coller" ni "se palucher" (dans ce sens). Noter que "se taper" et "se payer" sont plus polysémiques.

Comment: Bien qu'on puisse se palucher dans les bouchons pour passer le temps, il faut cependant rester discret. Si on peut discuter de l'emploi des autres, à priori ce terme-là est à proscrire pour la signification demandée...

Comment: @MathieuBouville À propos de *polysémique*, je n’utilise pas "*se coller*" dans ce sens-là, moi non plus, surtout que je l’associe avant tout au sens « *Je m'y colle/mets de ce pas* », dont la connotation n’est pas aussi *à contrecœur*. "*Se payer*", quant à lui, me fait plutôt penser au sens positif : « *Je me suis payé un petit luxe* ».

Answer (score 1):

En **français du Québec**, on ne connaît pas à mon avis le verbe *(se) coltiner* (je note que l'[Académie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/coltiner) déconseille son emploi à l'écrit etc., bof.) ni ne reconnaît *se [coller](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coller)*, *se [palucher](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/palucher)* ou [*refiler*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/refiler) dans le sens en question. Pas plus que *se [payer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/payer#fr-verb)*, qu'on connaît sans doute soit avec *du bon temps*, soit littéralement avec un objet (s'offrir), soit avec *la tête de quelqu'un* pour se moquer de quelqu'un qu'on associerait sans doute au français métropolitain.

Dans ma région la réponse est plus facile parce qu'à mon avis seul [*se taper*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_taper), familier, très courant à l'oral, utilisé comme dans l'exemple en question, est très fréquemment employé. On emploie probablement aussi *se [farcir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/farcir)*, familier, mais dans une bien moindre mesure (et je le trouve d'un registre moins familier que *se taper* par ailleurs). D'autre part on comprendrait certainement [*se faire chier à*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_chier) faire quelque chose, vulgaire, connotant peut-être l'*effort* plus que les deux autres.